# Memory Error While Preprocessing Using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a project to classify dog breeds using a CNN in Keras. While preprocessing the data, I am getting this memory error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9TkG.png. What should I do?

Comment: Can you show code of `path_to_tensor`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `data generator`.

You get this error because your machine doesn't have enough RAM to fit all the data on it. If you write the generator then you can get as much data as you need and then you can use `model.fit_generator()`. With this, you grab some amount of data, preprocess it, and forward it to model, grab another batch of data, preprocess it and forward to the model and so on.

You can find out more [here](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)